# HTML Entities to hex

Tags: php

How to convert html entities to hex?
I used this code

```
$username = preg_replace_callback('/[\x{80}-\x{10FFFF}]/u', function ($m) {
        $char = current($m);
        $utf = iconv('UTF-8', 'UCS-4', $char);
        return sprintf("&#x%s;", ltrim(strtoupper(bin2hex($utf)), "0"));
    }, $username);
```

But it dosent convert chars like `<` and others.

Comment: What means exactly *"chars like < and others"*? And what is the goal of your code? Why do you want to change the username?

Comment: Im making an api, that would allow me to check users. I need to change the characters for the api. Im using curl combined with php and it dosent work when i have special chars. The `<` dosent convert to hex so it dosent send the request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look into the regex used `[\x{80}-\x{10FFFF}]`, you'll see that it would match all chars whose ASCII value(in hex) lies between 0x80 and 0x10FFFF

But if you take a look at the ASCII chart you see

[image]

The hex values of `<` and `>` are lower than `0x80`. Assuming you have gotten the regex from API publishers they probably want you to convert extended ASCII chars such as these so it won't cause any problem whatsoever. But you can just edit the regex and get it to work for other characters as well

[image]